# SAQL Date format conversion

Tags: datetime, saql

I am pulling in a date field from a secondary (Japan) SFDC org into our native org.  The format in the Japan org shows it as just a date (yyyy-MM-dd) but when I look at the date in the data connection link it comes in as yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' with all the timestamp showing as 0s.  I try to force the simple date format in the connection but the results still show the timestamp.  I am trying to make the conversion in the dataflow but it returns the following error message:

Something went wrong while executing the ConvertPOtoCloseDate node: expression data type, UNKNOWN, is not supported for field 'CloseDateJ' (02K80000000PROFEA4_03C0U000000LqZeUAK)

when I try converting with SAQL code    DATEVALUE('POdate__c') I get the following error message:

Something went wrong while executing the ConvertPOtoCloseDate node: invalid field expression DATEVALUE('POdate__c') for field 'CloseDate': Function doesn't have a type check definition: DATEVALUE (02K80000000PROFEA4_03C0U000000Lqb1UAC)

I need to add to this description the fact that our Japan Org POdate maps to the native org's Closedate so I am renaming the output to Closedate and appending the Japan "CloseDate" to our native "CloseDate".

Answer (score 0):

The error "Function doesn't have a type check definition" is returned when the function name is wrong (including wrong casing).  I don't see a datevalue function in the [SAQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_date.htm). Should you be trying to [toDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_toDate.htm) function?